# Extend HashMap to return empty HashSet for non-found keys

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I want to make a HashMap which contains HashSets as values and returns an empty HashSet when the key is not found.

```
public class IsbnHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    protected V defaultValue;
    public IsbnHashMap(V defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
    @Override
    public V get(Object k) {
        return containsKey(k) ? super.get(k) : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

However my implementation does not work.

```
private static IsbnHashMap<String, HashSet<String>> isbnToId = new IsbnHashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
```

This returns "HashSet cannot be applied". If I try to change `K,V` in `IsbnHashMap` to `<String, HashSet<String>>` I get some funky errors as well. How can I implement this?

Comment: You're not passing anything to the constructor... (I'd advise against this, to be honest - it's significantly changing the behaviour developers would expect from a `Map`, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: Your contract (return empty HashSet) is not consistant with your implementation, since (a) there is no guarantee that the object from the constructor is empty, and more importantly (b) once it's been returned as a result of a not found lookup, the receiver could add data to it

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend using a properly designed library for this, like Guava's `Multimap`, which does all this correctly without violating interface contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it should be noted that in Java-8 you can use instead:

```
isbnToId.computeIfAbsent(isbn, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(_id);
```

Second, if you really want to do something like this in previous Java versions, you'd better to create separate method for this purpose (for example, `getOrDefault()`) in order not to violate the contract. Third, you need to create `new HashSet<>()` for every new key. If you return the same instance, it will be shared between given keys. If you don't expect users to modify it, it's better to use unmodifiable `Collections.emptySet()` as default value. This way users may safely do `isbnToId.getOrDefault(isbn).contains(_id)`, but trying `isbnToId.getOrDefault(isbn).add(_id)` will result in exception. If you want to support the modification (prior to Java-8), you can, for example, pass the element class to the constructor instead:

```
public static class MyMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private Class<?> clazz;

    public MyMap(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public V getOrCompute(K key) {
        V v = get(key);
        if(v == null) {
            try {
                v = (V) clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            put(key, v);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
MyMap<String, Set<String>> map = new MyMap<>(HashSet.class);
map.getOrCompute("a").add("b");
map.getOrCompute("a").add("c");
map.getOrCompute("d").add("e");
System.out.println(map); // {a=[b, c], d=[e]}
```

Here we assume that instantiating the passed class with default constructor is ok. An alternative would be to pass the factory interface which is capable to produce the default values.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet said ...

```
private static IsbnHashMap<String, HashSet<String>> isbnToId = new IsbnHashMap<String, HashSet<String>>(new HashSet<String>());
```

... however, that would return the same default object as Dunni pointed out.

So this will do:

```
private static HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> isbnToId = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

public static void coupleIsbnToId(String isbn, String _id) {
    if (!isbnToId.containsKey(isbn)) {
        isbnToId.put(isbn, new HashSet<String>());
    }
    isbnToId.get(isbn).add(_id);
}
```

Comment: Just FTR: If you do it like that, it could have some nasty consequences (e.g. if you get the default value HashSet and it is then manipulated later in the application, it will reflect of course the default value HashSet, since it still is the same object). So beware the consequences of this.